# How do I find OccupancyGrid message data, and how do I use it with QImage?

Tags: navigation, occupancy-grid, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm a real amateur and just started not long ago, and I'm currently using LIDAR and an aerial vehicle. Basically I'm stucked at this situation where I don't know how am I gonna find out the OccupancyGrid message data and how to use it.

void QNode::parsemap( const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg )
{

if( mapImage == NULL ) {
mapImage = new QImage( 240, 350, QImage::Format_RGB888 );
}

// copy map from msg to mapImage.

yeah, I'm stucked here trying to copy the map from the message data to mapImage(QImage).

I'm a real real real amateur... so don't be too hard on me if I'm asking a very simple question. I really hope that you guys would be able to help this friend in need. Thank you all, in advance. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188263/how-do-i-find-occupancygrid-message-data,-and-how-do-i-use-it-with-qimage?/) by [jeremyethankoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/19877/jeremyethankoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at the OccupancyGrid message (i.e., `rosmsg show nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid`), there are member fields for width, height, and the binary data. There are multiple ways of creating a QImage given that data; I haven't run the following (you may need to futz with the cast of the `msg->data`), but you can do something like:

```
const unsigned char* databeg = &(msg->data.front());
QImage img(databeg, msg->info.width, msg->info.height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

Note that there are additional considerations of which you must be aware. For instance, as stated in the QImage documentation, the data buffer **must** remain valid throughout the life of the QImage. So you might want to store the data, say as a QByteArray:

```
QByteArray m_data;
...
void QNode::parsemap( const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg ) {
    const unsigned char* databeg = &(msg->data.front());
    m_data = QByteArray(databeg, msg->data.size());
    QImage img((uchar*)m_data.data(), msg->info.width, msg->info.height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    ...
}
```

That should be enough to get you on your way...

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeremyethankoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/19877/jeremyethankoh/) on 2014-08-03**:
Hey Kramer, I've tried it and I have some debugging problems. I've an error stating "invalid conversion from 'const signed char*' to 'const unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]". I not sure how to get pass it! ):

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-08-07**:
As I mentioned, you may need to cast. For instance, the line:

```
QImage img((uchar*)m_data.data(), msg->info.width, msg->info.height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

casts the `const signed char*` result of `m_data.data()` to a `const unsigned char*`.

**Comment by [jeremyethankoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/19877/jeremyethankoh/) on 2014-08-07**:
Ahhhh, understand. I got it going already, somehow. :) But I have a new problem.. it's that the QImage is flipped vertically even though the codes are for the first pixels to the last... @kramer

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-08-08**:
Yes, it happens. :) You may have to do some byte moving, depending on the received data's ordering. You can write that yourself (fast & efficient data manipulation within an array is kinda a bread-and-butter CS task), but I suggest you look at QImage's functions (e.g., `mirrored`).